# what does eventually mean in the following question ? thanks

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\phi < f $, $g_n \to f $ pointwise, $g_n = inf_{k \geq n} f_k $. MY books says that 'eventually' $g_n \geq \phi$. What do they mean by eventually? Also to show this, they do the following:

Let $A_k = \{ x : g_k(x) \geq \phi \} $.

I understand that $A_k \subseteq A_{k+1} $, but i dont understant why $\cup_{k}^{\infty} A_k = \mathbb{R} $. Can someone explain me this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Eventually" = "When ignoring finitely many initial temrs"; for example the sequence $1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,\ldots$ is "eventually constant. 
Formally in your case:

> There exists an $n_0$ such that $g_n\ge \phi$ for all $n\ge n_0$. It appears that this is meant pointwise, i.e. $n_0$ may depend on $x$.

Another handy formulations is: For *almost* all $n$, $g_n(x)\ge \phi$.

You can conclude $\bigcup A_k=\mathbb R$ because you know that for all $x$ there exixts a $k$ such that $g_k(x)\ge \phi$.

Comment: but in real analysis $for almost all $ does it not mean except on a null set ? Im confused now